# Why do I get the letter 'e' instead of the value I gave it?

Tags: c++

I have this piece of code, and I want if someone is older than 30 (general) that person needs to be spoken to with good language for old people and otherwise normal language, but if I run this the piece of older than 30 works I get "u" but otherwise I get te letter "e" instead of "je", does someone know what is wrong?

```
char bejaard = 'je';
        if (jaar-gJaar > 30){
            bejaard = 'u';
        }

        cout << "Er wordt nu een rekensom gegeven waarbij "<< bejaard <<" het antwoord moet schatten:"
             << endl << random1 << "x" << random2 << endl;
```

Comment: How do you expect to put **two** characters in a variable that holds **one**?

Comment: Got it thanks, haha stupid me sometimes

Comment: ist this 'je' a char for you#?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ that is correct but in dutch there is a difference between you and you, for different people of age

Comment: `'je'` is actually a valid character (it is a multicharacter literal).  But it has type `int` and an implementation-defined value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'je'` is a *multicharacter literal* with an implementation-defined value: `'e'` +  2<sup>8</sup> * `'j'` is common. It is an `int` type. Importantly it's not syntactically invalid, although some compilers can warn you of their use.

You are most likely overflowing the `char` to which this is being assigned, with undefined or implementation defined results.

(It's plausible that `'e'` is obtained from `'e'` +  2<sup>8</sup> * `'j'` as that modulo 256 is `'e'`: an 8 bit `char` is practically ubiquitous).

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you're using a char type and you could be overflowing it.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler should be giving you a warning for this line.

```
char bejaard = 'je';
```

Single quotes `'` are used for declaring single characters, since je is two characters it needs to be a null terminated string which are in double quotes `"`.

It should be:

```
const char* bejaard = "je";
```

Since it's more than one character long.

`bejaard` will need consistent typing so you'll also need to change the assignment in the if statement:

```
 bejaard = "u";
```

Comment: With g++, you can pass -wmultichar

Comment: A compiler is not required to give any warning or other diagnostic about use of multicharacter literals (like `'je'`)